# Do Chicken lay eggs when loaded in the Spawn Chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've built a Chicken Generator and I want it to generate Raw Chicken Meat. However, I'm not sure if they lay eggs when loaded into the [Spawn Chunks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_chunk).
**So, do they lay eggs or I've built the Generator for nothing?**

*Note: I want to know this because I want for the Generator to work wherever I am in the world.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, chickens will lay eggs when they are loaded in the spawn chucks. See the behavior section [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chicken). It says 'While in a loaded chunk, a chicken will lay one egg every 5 to 10 minutes (6000 to 12000 ticks), unless it is (or was) a part of a chicken jockey.' and as spawn chunks are always loaded, the chickens will continue to lay eggs.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: I updated the answer to include one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was 5-10 minutes, but other sites say 8 minutes. Chickenbaby need 8m to grow.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Egg